# How can I play my computer's audio in real time from a file

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, audio-streaming

I recently purchased some Samsung WAM1500 wireless speakers for my home, and while I am happy with them, the software from Samsung that controls them is a bit lacking. I would like to be able to transmit my desktop audio to the speakers but that feature is not supported by the software. The software can play local media files along with an assortment of select online music services, and my plex server also shows up as a source. My first idea was to create an audio file on my computer and somehow feed in my desktop audio, as it occurs, to this file which can then be read in real time by the music player. Put another way I'd like to create an audio file on my computer that is open for reading and writing, and as the input takes my desktop audio but can also be simultaneously read by other programs. Is this sort of thing possible? Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is probably going to be solved using what is called *transcoding*, and the network mechanism is probably going to be "RTP". Plex does seem to support both in some manner, but whether you can set it up to play the real-time PC-audio stream is uncertain. In principle it can: you'd pipe the audio stream to the transcoding server(software)  which broadcasts using rtp protocol, your device would then open the rtp stream.

Comment: some of the barebones steps showing the principle: (linux) Note that plex was, at some early stage, an offshoot of XBMC which is also discussed http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/11735/using-pi-to-stream-all-audio-output-from-my-pc-to-my-stereo